# Send message via TCP Sockets - Java (closed)

Tags: java, android, sockets, tcp

I'm trying to send a message via TCP Socket in Android, but it'd not working. (My phone is the client)

Here's the code from the Class TCPClient:

```
public class TcpClient {
    public static String SERVER_IP = "192.168.200.1"; //server IP address
    public static final int SERVER_PORT = 1500;
    // message to send to the server
    private String mServerMessage;
    // sends message received notifications
    private OnMessageReceived mMessageListener = null;
    // while this is true, the server will continue running
    private boolean mRun = false;
    // used to send messages
    private PrintWriter mBufferOut;
    // used to read messages from the server
    private BufferedReader mBufferIn;
    private Socket socket;
    private Context context;
    /**
     * Constructor of the class. OnMessagedReceived listens for the messages received from server
     */
    public TcpClient(OnMessageReceived listener) {
        mMessageListener = listener;
    }

    /**
     * Sends the message entered by client to the server
     *
     * param message text entered by client
     */

    public String sendMessage(String message) {
        byte[] bytesToSend = message.getBytes();
        if (bytesToSend != null && socket != null && socket.isConnected()) {
            try {
                socket.getOutputStream().write(bytesToSend, 0, 9);
                return "deu";
            } catch (Exception e2) {
                e2.printStackTrace();
                return e2.getMessage();
            }
        }
        else return "aa";
    }

    /**
     * Close the connection and release the members
     */
    public void stopClient() {
        sendMessage("disconnecting");
        mRun = false;

        if (mBufferOut != null) {
            mBufferOut.flush();
            mBufferOut.close();
        }

        mMessageListener = null;
        mBufferIn = null;
        mBufferOut = null;
        mServerMessage = null;
    }

    public void run() {

        mRun = true;

        try {
            //here you must put your computer's IP address.
            InetAddress serverAddr = InetAddress.getByName(SERVER_IP);

            Log.e("TCP Client", "C: Connecting...");

            //create a socket to make the connection with the server
            socket = new Socket(serverAddr, SERVER_PORT);

            try {

                //sends the message to the server
                mBufferOut = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream())), true);

                //receives the message which the server sends back
                mBufferIn = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
                // send login name
                sendMessage("connected");

                //in this while the client listens for the messages sent by the server
                while (mRun) {

                    mServerMessage = mBufferIn.readLine();

                    if (mServerMessage != null && mMessageListener != null) {
                        //call the method messageReceived from MyActivity class
                        mMessageListener.messageReceived(mServerMessage);
                    }

                }

                Log.e("RESPONSE FROM SERVER", "S: Received Message: '" + mServerMessage + "'");

            } catch (Exception e) {

                Log.e("TCP", "S: Error", e);
            } finally {
                //the socket must be closed. It is not possible to reconnect to this socket
                // after it is closed, which means a new socket instance has to be created.
                socket.close();
            }

        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            e.getStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.getStackTrace();
        }

    }

    //Declare the interface. The method messageReceived(String message) will must be implemented in the Activity
    //class at on AsyncTask doInBackground
    public interface OnMessageReceived {
        public void messageReceived(String message);
    }

}
```

This is the code of my MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private Button btnInicio;
    private Button btnFinal;
    private Button btnRelatorio;
    private ImageView imgEcosonicsLogo;
    private TextView txtDataFinal;
    private TextView txtDataInicio;
    private Button btnConectar;
    private String recebido[];
    boolean connected = false;
    TcpClient mTcpClient;

    //COMUNICAÇÃO TCP
    public class ConnectTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, TcpClient> {

        @Override
        protected TcpClient doInBackground(String... message) {

            //we create a TCPClient object and
            mTcpClient = new TcpClient(new TcpClient.OnMessageReceived() {
                @Override
                //here the messageReceived method is implemented
                public void messageReceived(String message) {
                    //this method calls the onProgressUpdate
                    publishProgress(message);
                }
            });
            mTcpClient.run();

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(String... values) {
            super.onProgressUpdate(values);
        }
    }

    private void init() {

        final AlertDialog.Builder avisoData = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        avisoData.setTitle("Atenção!");
        avisoData.setMessage("A data inicial não pode ser depois da final");
        avisoData.setPositiveButton("OK!", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

            }
        });

        final AlertDialog.Builder avisoCon = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        avisoCon.setTitle("Atenção!");
        avisoCon.setMessage("Erro durante a conexão");

        final AlertDialog.Builder avisounkn = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        avisounkn.setTitle("Atenção!");
        avisounkn.setMessage("Erro unknow host");

        btnRelatorio = findViewById(R.id.btnRelatorio);
        btnRelatorio.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if (inicio_ano > final_ano)
                    avisoData.show();
                else if ((inicio_mes + 1) > (final_mes + 1) && inicio_ano == final_ano)
                    avisoData.show();
                if (inicio_dia > final_dia) {
                    if ((inicio_mes + 1) == (final_mes + 1))
                        avisoData.show();
                }
                if (mTcpClient != null) {
                    avisoCon.setMessage(mTcpClient.sendMessage("relatorio"));
                    avisoCon.show();
                }
                else
                    avisoCon.show();
            }
        });

        btnConectar = findViewById(R.id.btnConectar);
        btnConectar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (!connected) {
                    new ConnectTask().execute("");
                    btnConectar.setText("Desconectar");
                    connected = true;
                }
                else {
                    if (mTcpClient != null) {
                        mTcpClient.stopClient();
                        mTcpClient = null;
                    }
                    btnConectar.setText("Conectar");
                    connected = false;
                }
            }
        });
    }
    String string;

    int inicio_dia = 1;
    int inicio_mes = 0;
    int inicio_ano = 2019;
    int final_dia = 1;
    int final_mes = 0;
    int final_ano = 2019;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        txtDataFinal = findViewById(R.id.txtDataFinal);
        txtDataInicio = findViewById(R.id.txtDataInicio);
        btnInicio = findViewById(R.id.btnInicio);
        btnInicio.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Calendar rightNow = Calendar.getInstance();
                int year = rightNow.get(Calendar.YEAR);
                int month = rightNow.get(Calendar.MONTH);
                int dayOfMonth = rightNow.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
                DatePickerDialog datePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(MainActivity.this,
                        new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
                            public void onDateSet(DatePicker datePicker, int ano, int mes, int dia) {

                                inicio_dia = dia;
                                inicio_mes = mes;
                                inicio_ano = ano;

                                if (dia < 10) {
                                    if (mes < 10) {
                                        txtDataInicio.setText("0" + dia + "/" + "0" + (mes + 1) + "/" + ano);
                                    }
                                    else {
                                        txtDataInicio.setText("0" + dia + "/" + (mes + 1) + "/" + ano);
                                    }
                                }
                                else {
                                    if (mes < 10) {
                                        txtDataInicio.setText(dia + "/" + "0" + (mes + 1) + "/" + ano);
                                    }
                                    else {
                                        txtDataInicio.setText(dia + "/" + (mes + 1) + "/" + ano);
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        },year, month, dayOfMonth);
                datePickerDialog.show();
            }
        });

        btnFinal = findViewById(R.id.btnFinal);
        btnFinal.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Calendar rightNow = Calendar.getInstance();
                int year = rightNow.get(Calendar.YEAR);
                int month = rightNow.get(Calendar.MONTH);
                int dayOfMonth = rightNow.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
                DatePickerDialog datePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(MainActivity.this,
                        new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
                            public void onDateSet(DatePicker datePicker, int ano, int mes, int dia) {

                                final_ano = ano;
                                final_dia = dia;
                                final_mes = mes;

                                if (dia < 10) {
                                    if (mes < 10) {
                                        txtDataFinal.setText("0" + dia + "/" + "0" + (mes + 1) + "/" + ano);
                                    }
                                    else {
                                        txtDataFinal.setText("0" + dia + "/" + (mes + 1) + "/" + ano);
                                    }
                                }
                                else {
                                    if (mes < 10) {
                                        txtDataFinal.setText(dia + "/" + "0" + (mes + 1) + "/" + ano);
                                    }
                                    else {
                                        txtDataFinal.setText(dia + "/" + (mes + 1) + "/" + ano);
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        },year, month, dayOfMonth);
                datePickerDialog.show();
            }
        });

        imgEcosonicsLogo = findViewById(R.id.imgEcosonicsLogo);
        imgEcosonicsLogo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent();
                intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_BROWSABLE);
                intent.setData(Uri.parse("http://www.ecosonics.com.br"));
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
        init();
    }
}
```

Every time I press the btnRelatorio button, it shows the AlertDialog with no message and doesn't send anydata to the server.

Here's the message showed in the debug console:

```
W/ViewRootImpl[MainActivity]: Dropping event due to root view being removed: MotionEvent { action=ACTION_MOVE, actionButton=0, id[0]=0, x[0]=516.49677, y[0]=-390.2551, toolType[0]=TOOL_TYPE_FINGER, buttonState=0, metaState=0, flags=0x0, edgeFlags=0x0, pointerCount=1, historySize=0, eventTime=132921874, downTime=132921863, deviceId=3, source=0x1002 }
W/InputEventReceiver: Attempted to finish an input event but the input event receiver has already been disposed.
W/System.err: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
        at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1598)
W/System.err:     at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite(SocketOutputStream.java:108)
        at java.net.SocketOutputStream.write(SocketOutputStream.java:153)
        at br.com.ecosonics.ecosmanager_wifi.TcpClient.sendMessage(TcpClient.java:52)
        at br.com.ecosonics.ecosmanager_wifi.MainActivity$2.onClick(MainActivity.java:116)
W/System.err:     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6312)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:24802)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:790)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
W/System.err:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:169)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6521)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
```

PS: It sends the message "connected", warning that the client connected to the server
Sorry about my bad English, and I hope you can help me.

Comment: Also you are reading lines but you aren't writing lines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need to be sorry for your English!
it is perfectly fine :)

```
android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1598)
```

Above error is thrown when your application tries to perform any network operation on the main thread.

You may use the code below to force the operation or make a separate thread and perform the operation.

**Option 1: forcing**

```
    int SDK_INT = android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
    if (SDK_INT > 8) 
    {
        StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder()
                .permitAll().build();
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
        //your codes here

    }
```

**Option 2: separate thread**

```
Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                // do something in here
            }
        });
thread.start();
```

Comment: I would recommend using Option 2, as Option 1 will block any other operations on your main thread.